# How do I recover from a KDE Partition Manager crash?

Tags: kubuntu

I was using KDE partition manager to resize a partition.  It was working fine for about three hours and showed 4 hours to go when I went to bed last night .... I got to the computer this morning and it had locked-up and was not responsive so I had to reboot.  Now the disk shows the following:

[kparted screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKaot.png)

The /dev/sdd4 was being merged with the unallocated partition of 68.36GiB.  Originally the smaller partition was at the beginning of the disk, and the larger one was immediately after that, so the data had to be moved to the beginning of the disk ...
I'm not sure where I can find anything in any logs, I've tried to find something.

It was ext4 - is it possible to be recovered?
thank you

P.S.
I ran TestDisk and this is what it said:

TestDisk 7.0, Data Recovery Utility, April 2015
Christophe GRENIER 
http://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/sdd - 2000 GB / 1863 GiB - CHS 243201 255 63

The harddisk (2000 GB / 1863 GiB) seems too small! (< 4000 GB / 3726 GiB)
Check the harddisk size: HD jumpers settings, BIOS detection...

The following partitions can't be recovered:
     Partition               Start         End  Size in sectors
   Linux                125389 123 47 358632 134 30 3747049472   [Data]
   Linux                125389 253 49 358633   9 32 3747049472   [Data]
   Linux                125394 181 36 358637 192 19 3747049472   [Data]
   Linux                125397 229 17 358640 239 63 3747049472   [Data]
   Linux                125399 109 23 358642 120  6 3747049472   [Data]
   Linux                125399 141 55 358642 152 38 3747049472   [Data]

> HPFS - NTFS          243200 254 63 486401 253 62 3907024002

I'm surprised that ext4 can be trashed, and the utilities for moving the data can be "broken" that easily - so I'm hoping that someone may be able to help here please!

Comment: Well, if you computer crashed during the move, then your partition is in broken. All the data should be there but it might be hard to recover. When partition is extended on the left, KPM takes first block of 128520 sectors and moves it to a new location at the start of the disk, then takes the second block and moves it left. So if your computer got stuck, your partition should look like (Correct partition data, then at some unknown point 68 GB of old data that was already moved to the beginning and then the remainder of the data). This is probably too hard for testdisk.

Comment: thank you for the reply @AndriusŠtikonas.  does anyone know how I can identify when the machine crashed?  I'm trying to find it in the logs - is there a specific log I should look at?